# Generate Call Graph in Android

Tags: android, profiling, call-graph

What are possible tools to generate the call graph of an android application in eclipse? I would like to know which methods interact together...but i can't seem to find anything helpful. I have read something about Oprofile but many persons said that it is not working and contains many problems. I'd like to visualize my code in android to develop better applications.

Thank you

Comment: have you got any tool to get call graph . I am having same problem. Guide me

Comment: Did you ever find anything to use for this? I'm also looking for something similar but for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think the traceview tool is exactly what you are looking for.  It show how much time each method takes and shows you the method stack.  [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) are some tips on how to use it.

Comment: isn't traceview more like a profiler? i would like to have the call graph of the application...like which class is calling which..and so on..thank u